# How can I configure an at least one EF code first relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(f => f.Types).WithMany().Map(f => f.ToTable("FooType"));
```

However, as I understand it, this just means `Foo` *can* have multiple `FooType`s.  I want it such that `Foo` has at least one `FooType`. I've tried adding in a required somewhere along the line, but it doesn't seem to let me.  How can I accomplish this?